# How to keep a global DataContext object updated in different running instances of the application?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using a single global DataContext object for my entire application. The application should work in a network environment where multiple instances of it work simultaneously with a shared SQL database.

The database changes in one application are not reflected in other instances until I call DataContext.Refresh method. Problem is this function is time consuming and I cannot change my code back to using different datacontext objects for different operations.

What should I do to always keep the datacontext object in each application updated?

Comment: what type of application is this? web/wpf/winforms (or all?). either way, a global DC is a crazy thing to do.

Comment: the scariest statement of all is "The application should work in a network environment". Yeah, good luck with that. May god have mercy on your soul.

Comment: @RPM1984: A web application and several windows applications.

Comment: Lol, Thanks for the support guys. It seems that I have to go through some long days of re-coding and debugging.

Comment: Hehe well look, i don't know how to help you here - because i've never implemented this scenario. My DB connections have always been either wrapping in a using statement (open late, close early), or instantiated per HTTP request by a DI container. Doing this 'singleton-like' approach will cause immense locking.

Answer (score 0):

[RefreshMode Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.refreshmode.aspx) is the correct bit. Just a matter of deciding when to use it, and using the DataContext correctly. Think of the DataContext as a unit-of-work, and flag the refresh mode when your prepairing a submit (like KeepChanges or something). In that way, the users info is pushed (or bubbles up on conflict) and it's automagically updated with the freshest stuff in the database.

I think everyone else has rightly pointed out the wrongness of a global datacontext. You'd either have to set a refresh time or give the user a button to refresh if you wanted to update their display more frequently. I don't know of another way there.